# accidentally removed xorg with ubuntu-desktop and now my mouse/keybord wont work in the login screen

Tags: xubuntu, keyboard, mouse

So, yesterday i installed a new shell. Xubuntu to be more exact.
So today i tried to remove ubuntu-desktop, well.

Everything working perfectly, i rebooted my computer and still working.

Then i went to the terminal and typed

> sudo apt-get autoremove

Everything still working so i decided to logoff
that's when I realized that my mouse and keyboard did not work anymore.

I rebooted and it continues the same way.

Ps:

1. The keyboard works perfectly  in Grub and recovery mode.
2. Dpkg gives me "Failed to fetch" in every file.e
3. The same thing happens in the recovery root using apt-get update and etc "Failed to fetch"

I'm stuck at the login screen

There is a way to fix this?

Update 1:

Keyboard don't work at all at login screen, can't use Ctrl+alt+F1" and as said, Every command like that give failed to fetch in every file (using recovery mode root)

The only way to turn off the computer while in the login screen is by pressing the power button in my pc. and nope, the other kernel don't work at all. Also i tried the apt update again and i get this "chmod 0700 of directory /var/cache/archives/partial failed - setupAPTPartialDirectory (30: Read-only file system)

Ubuntu 17.04

Comment: Does Ctrl+Alt+F1 do anything at the login screen? It should give you a text-based [virtual console](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_console). (Alt+F7 should take you back to the GUI.) On the virtual console Ctrl+Alt+F1 switches to, you may be able to log in. Depending how your computer accesses the Internet and how the network connection is managed, you *might* be able to use it from the virtual console while not logged into a graphical session. Does `ping www.google.com` work on that virtual console? (Ctrl+C stops it.) Does `sudo apt update` give errors? Please **[edit]** with details.

Comment: Keyboard don't work at all at login screen, can't use Ctrl+alt+F1" and as said, Every command like that give failed to fetch in every file (using recovery mode root)

Comment: Can you select a different kernel version in the GRUB menu? Does the keyboard with any of them? Btw even if the it doesn't otherwise seem to do anything, Ctrl+Alt+F1 *might* still work--but I'll take your comment as saying you've tried and it didn't. You mentioned you rebooted at the login screen. How did you do this? Did you power cycle the machine? Does [Alt+SysRq+REISUB](https://askubuntu.com/a/36717) work there? If REISUB does work, that's useful information about what might be wrong (because it means the keyboard does work for at least that) and also that's preferable to the reset button.

Comment: The only way to turn off the computer while in the login screen is by pressing the power button in my pc.
and nope, the other kernel don't work at all.

Also i tried the apt update again and i get this "chmod 0700 of directory /var/cache/archives/partial failed - setupAPTPartialDirectory (30:  Read-only file system)

Comment: The "Failed to fetch" error suggests your Internet connection doesn't work in recovery mode, which is to be expected. Do you connect through Ethernet, WiFi, or something else? Are your keyboard/mouse at all special? Wireless? Do they require setup to be used with a new machine? (Or is it a laptop keyboard?) Did you install the `xubuntu-desktop` package with `apt-get`? If not, how? Before `sudo apt-get autoremove` what did you run? Was it `sudo apt-get remove ubuntu-desktop`? What Ubuntu version is this? I recommend you **[edit]** your question with all the information you've given in comments.

Comment: I use Ethernet, My keyboard and mouse are both USB.
They didn't require any setup to be used.
Yuep, i installed the xubuntu-desktop package with apt-get

Comment: i used 

>sudo apt-get remove unity unity-2d unity-2d-common unity-2d-panel unity-2d-shell unity-2d-spread unity-asset-pool unity-common unity-lens-applications unity-lens-files unity-lens-music unity-lens-video unity-scope-musicstores unity-scope-video-remote unity-services indicator-messages indicator-status-provider-mc5 appmenu-qt appmenu-gtk appmenu-gtk3 lightdm xserver-xorg unity-greeter overlay-scrollbar zeitgeist zeitgeist-core zeitgeist-datahub activity-log-manager-common activity-log-manager-control-center
>sudo purge unity8
>sudo apt autoremove

Comment: Were both `sudo apt-get remove ...` and `sudo apt autoremove` run *after* `sudo apt-get install xubuntu-desktop`? That might explain why you're having problems: a GUI login screen usually needs `lightdm` and `xserver-xorg`. (Removing them would also remove the `xubuntu-desktop` metapackage.) If the GUI login screen still *looked* the same, that's strange, though. In the Recovery Menu can you select "Drop to root shell prompt with networking"? Then does `ping www.google.com` work? (Ctrl+C cancels it.) *If not*, does `sudo service network-manager start` show errors and can you `ping` after that?

Comment: i did the sudo apt-get remove and sudo apt autoremove after doing apt-get install xubuntu-desktop.

Also i did the ping www.google.com
I get " Ping: www.google.com: temporary failure in name resolution"
update:
I did something really bad, every .conf file got deleted haha
i don't have the resolv.conf

Comment: How and when were .conf files deleted? Can you explain that fully in your question? Was it before you tried to switch to Xfce? This may help explain why your keyboard and mouse are don't work on the graphical login screen (as if the problem were just that Xorg and LightDM were removed, REISUB should be unaffected). I recommend you **[edit]** your question again with a full explanation of this, as well as all the information in comments that didn't make it into your last edit. The edits should help other people understand what is going on so they may help too (and also they bump your question).

Comment: Have you managed to solve the issue? I am having the same problem.